# Change outline color of a Material 3 switch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to find a way to change the outline Color of a material 3 switch and for some odd reason I cannot find a way, I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how I can do that in both XML and Code behind.

Also, I would appreciate it if you could guide me to the documentation for Material 3 components!

My current switch looks like the following:

```
<com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:checked="true"
android:text="Material 3"/>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try to change `app:trackDecoration` in XML or `setTrackDecorationDrawable` via code. It's default value is `@drawable/mtrl_switch_track_decoration` which you can refer in order to change the outline color.

Comment: To customize your MaterialSwitch you can use `app:thumb` and `app:track` XML attribues.

Comment: @ItzDavi It might be possible that ChatGPT gives similar response, but I've written this down on my own using the reference from the official documentation which can be checked [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Switch.md) and as you are saying that this is a ChatGPT generated comment that means you have checked for an answer on ChatGPT but I didn't. If ChatGPT gives answers to every question with 100% accuracy, then why anyone will ask a question here.

Comment: Can you guys help me with some example code

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Switch.md#switch-theming-example) from material components:

#### 1. Define your new `MaterialSwitch` style

In your `styles.xml` define your new style defining your `materialThemeOverlay` item

> ```
> <style name="Your.Style.Name" parent="Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.MaterialSwitch">
>     <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Switch</item>
> </style>
> ```

#### 2. Define your `ThemeOverlay`

> ```
> <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Switch" parent="">
>     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pink_200</item>
>     <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/pink_100</item>
> </style>
> ```

And here you have two ways: implementing your style to **all** `MaterialSwitch` or applying manually your style to your `MaterialSwitch`.

#### 3. Apply the style to all `MaterialSwitch`

In your primary style in styles.xml, apply your new style for all `MaterialSwitch`

> ```
> <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.*">
>     ...
>     <item name="materialSwitchStyle">@style/Widget.App.Switch</item>
> </style>
> ```

#### 3.1 Apply the style for single-case `MaterialSwitch`

> ```
> <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
>         ...
>     style="@style/Widget.App.Switch"
>     />
> ```

Comment: How about programmatically changing this?

Comment: You technically could but read the documentation, it's deprecated, avoid deprecation and leave them as a last resort @FreakyAli

Comment: Programmatically changing values is deprecated? Weird!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Using XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        app:trackDecorationTint="#AA3710" />

    <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        app:trackDecorationTint="#AA3710" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Here, you need to set track outline color using `app:trackDecorationTint="#AA3710"` & set `#AA3710` to any color you want. If you provide a single-color like in the sample above, that same color will be used for all states like checked, unchecked, disabled. To provide separate color for each state, you can pass reference to state list XML file of colors.

The output

[image: Two material switches showing outline color customization]

---

2. Using Code (Java)

Separate color for each state

```java
int[][] states = new int[][]{
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
};
int[] colors = new int[]{
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.RED,
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.BLUE
};
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
switchMaterial.setTrackDecorationTintList(colorStateList);
```

Same color for all states

```java
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED);
switchMaterial.setTrackDecorationTintList(singleColorcolorStateListStateList);
```

Comment: Please, read this https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Switch.md#switch-states-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Just override this color for your app's theme:

```
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorOutline">@color/my_outline_color</item>
</style>
```